# creating schemas inside functions on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a schema after inserting a new "something"
What is the correct syntax on PostgreSQL14 (or even older versions) that will give me the same as
`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ischema` where ischema is the function input, ischema?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blah_insert_something(
    IN iname varchar,
    IN ischema varchar
) RETURNS UUID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    result UUID;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO internal.something(name, schema, data)
    VALUES ($1, $2, '{}')
    RETURNING id INTO result;

    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "$2";

    RETURN result;
END;
$$
```

Currently it literally creates a schema called $2, if I remove the quotes or use single quotes, it complains about invalid syntax. If I put ischema in there and run

```
SELECT blah_insert_something('test', 'testing')
```

it literally creates a schema called `ischema` instead of `testing`.

What is the correct syntax to make this demo code work?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`. Use the `format()` function.

Comment: Format works well with @nbk's solution: CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ' || format('prefix_%I', $2) || ';'; I will need to be very careful about SQL injection here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function makes not much sense but you need dynamic sql for that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blah_insert_something(
    IN iname varchar,
    IN ischema varchar
) RETURNS UUID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
    result UUID;
    stmt text;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO internal.something(name, schema, data)
    VALUES ($1, $2, '{}')
    RETURNING id INTO result;

     
     stmt = 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ' || $2 || ';';
    

     EXECUTE stmt;
    

    RETURN result;
END;
$$
```

Comment: a table to track all "entities" which is inside the internal schema and then a schema for each entity so their data is completely separate

Comment: I had to remove the IMMEDIATE part and I discovered that my semicolon is in the wrong place, it should be after the $$, not after END, otherwise this solution works, thanks!